# Validar captcha antes de enviar formulário

Tags: php, html, session, captcha

Preciso de um captcha bem simples, mas que possa ser validado antes do formulário ser enviado, como posso fazer isso?

Atualmente uso esse:

**index.html**

```
<form method="post" action="valida.php" id="form" name="form">
    <!-- campos -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Captcha*:<img src="captcha.php?l=105&a=35&tf=15&ql=5"></label>
        <input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra" class="form-control input-lg" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

**captcha.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

function captcha($largura,$altura,$tamanho_fonte,$quantidade_letras){
    $imagem = imagecreate($largura,$altura); 
    $fonte = "verdana.ttf";
    $preto  = imagecolorallocate($imagem,243,243,243);
    $branco = imagecolorallocate($imagem,0,151,182);

    $palavra = substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVYXWZ23456789"),0,($quantidade_letras));
    $_SESSION["palavra"] = $palavra; 
    for($i = 1; $i <= $quantidade_letras; $i++){
        imagettftext($imagem,$tamanho_fonte,rand(0,0),($tamanho_fonte*$i),($tamanho_fonte + 10),$branco,$fonte,substr($palavra,($i-1),1));
    }
    imagejpeg($imagem);
    imagedestroy($imagem);
}

$largura = $_GET["l"];
$altura = $_GET["a"];
$tamanho_fonte = $_GET["tf"];
$quantidade_letras = $_GET["ql"];
captcha($largura,$altura,$tamanho_fonte,$quantidade_letras);
?>
```

**valida.php**

```
if ($_POST["palavra"] == $_SESSION["palavra"]) {
    //...
}
```

mas não sei como verificar se o captcha foi preenchido corretamente antes de enviar o formulário.

Comment: Com esse `if` que tem em baixo não faz isso?

Comment: sim, mas pra chegar ali o formulário já foi enviado, eu queria que ele verificasse antes de enviar. Tem como @Miguel?

Comment: O problema é a definição de "já foi enviado". "Não" há como você saber se está preenchido corretamente (ou não), sem que envie uma requisição ao servidor. O que você pode fazer é criar um ajax para quando o usuário digitar enviar uma requisição ao servidor. Então retornar ao javascript se está correto ou não. Se estiver correto o usuário poderá permitir o usuário enviar o formulário. Eu aconselharia usar o Google ReCaptcha, para tal finalidade, de qualquer forma.

Comment: Entendi, mas não tem como comparar o que o cara ta digitando com o que está em sessão @Inkeliz? Pensei nisso agr mas não sei se funcionaria nem como seria.

Comment: Existe, desde que use Javascript para essa finalidade. Mas qual seria o real intuito de verificar o captcha antes de enviar o formulário? Acredito que exista alguma outra solução, melhor do que fazer duas requisições, sendo uma apenas para verificar o captcha.

Comment: É que o formulário é integrado com uma ferramenta externa para computar os dados enviados e isso é feito no ato do envio do formulário, então se o captcha estiver certo ou não ele vai computar de qualquer forma se eu tiver de enviar pra verificar.

Comment: Utilize recaptcha no google, entre https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html é mais facil de grátis e tem tutorial facilidade para fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, consegui da seguinte forma:

No meu input do captcha em chamo uma função `Cap()`:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="form" name="form">
    <!-- campos -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Captcha*:<img src="captcha.php?l=105&a=35&tf=15&ql=5"></label>
        <input type="text" name="palavra" id="palavra" class="form-control input-lg" onkeyup="Cap();" required>
    </div>
</form>
```

A função `Cap()` por sua vez envia o form via ajax para verificar o captcha e habilitar ou desabilitar o botão de envio do formulário de acordo com a resposta.:

```
<script>
    function Cap(){
        var form = $("#form").serializeArray();
        var url = "valida.php";
        if($("#palavra").val().length){
            $.post(url, form, function(data){
                if(data == 'error'){
                    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
                }else{
                    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("submit").prop("disabled", true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

O valida.php ficou assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_POST["palavra"] == $_SESSION["palavra"]) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

O captcha.php permaneceu da mesma forma. Não sei se é a melhor forma de se fazer, mas está funcionando bem e suprindo a necessidade atual.

Answer (score 1):

No método ou função que trata o envio do formulário, você poderá consultar o `Captcha` via `Ajax`, então, se estiver OK, você pode submeter os demais dados do formulário.